# Annotation geo algolia symfony

Tags: symfony, algolia

Do you know can i add the annotation geo or geologic in entity symfony to obtain like this

```
"_geoloc": {
"lat": 31.222219,
"lng": 121.458061
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do:

```
/**
 * @Algolia\Attribute(algoliaName="_geoloc")
 */
public function getGeoloc()
{
    return array("lat" => $this->getLat(), "lng" => $this->getLng());
}
```

Comment: Where did you found this function? Is there a link to the docs which describes the different functions?

Comment: I wrote it, it's a way to define attributes based on custom functions; see https://github.com/algolia/AlgoliaSearchBundle#indexing-entity-properties-or-methods.